# How to convert an array of pixel value data in R

Tags: r, image, multidimensional-array

I use the biOps package in R to extract RGB values from an image. As an example, I have an image of 10x10 pixels. The result is an array of `x[1:10,1:10,1]` for Red, `x[1:10,1:10,2]` for Green and `x[1:10,1:10,3]` for Blue. I want to convert this to a dataframe like below:

(Pixel X position, Pixel Y position, Red value, Green Value, Blue value)

```
X  Y  R   G   B
1  1  255 255 255
1  2  255 255 255
1  3  0   0   0
...
10 10 255 255 255
```

IMPORTANT: I do not always know the size of the pixels, I use 10x10 as an example only.

How do I do this in R? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
B

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow RUser. What did you tried? What problems are you facing?

Comment: It will take some learning on your part, but this is what `cast` does, or maybe just `melt` are for (package `reshape2`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reshape2` library can make this easy. First let's create some test data

x <- array(sapply(1:3, function(i) sample(0:9, 100, replace=T)+i*10), 
    dim=c(10,10,3))

This is an array `x` like yours with dim `c(10,10,3)`. Now we can melt the data and cast it how we like

```
mm <- melt(x, varnames=c("X","Y","Color"))
mm$Color <- factor(mm$Color, levels=1:3, labels=c("Red","Blue","Green"))
xx <- dcast(mm, X+Y~Color)
head(xx)
```

And that produces data like

```
  X Y Red Blue Green
1 1 1  10   26    33
2 1 2  12   23    31
3 1 3  13   25    32
4 1 4  18   24    31
5 1 5  18   26    35
6 1 6  14   24    36
```

Note that the `reshape` command didn't care that is was `10x10` it will just unwarp each dimension of your array. You will just want to make sure the third dimension is 3 to correspond to the three colors.